# Python - Calculate field density in csv/tsv file

Tags: python, csv, mapreduce, field, distributed-computing

Hi suppose if i have a tab seperated file like this (each field separated by tab spaces):

```
Name    ID    Country    GPA
Tom    id1    USA        3.4
Jon    id2    Canada    
Amy           UK         3.0
Kevin  id4    Scotland    
Kris                     3.1
```

Here the density of name = 1.0 that is 100% 
density of ID is 0.6 that is 60%  (2 fields missing)
density of Country is 0.8 
density of GPA is also 0.6

How to find this out for for a file using python? Also I need an algo that's efficient and fast since I need to do this for thousands of files worth more than 40 GB. Map reduce code also works.
Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: how to decide here that whether `UK` belongs to `country` not `ID`?

Comment: Number of tab spaces between them. Here I used 4 spaces as 1 tab value for this demo. The data files that i have are quite organized, so there wont be issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import izip
import csv

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    keys = next(reader)
    counts = Counter()
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        counts.update(k for k, v in izip(keys, row) if v)
    line_count = i + 1
    for k in keys:
        print k, 'density:', 1.0 * counts[k] / line_count
```

Comment: @sberry.  Thanks.  I had an off by one error that I did not recognize until i looked at your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open(name,'r')
head = f.readline().strip().split('\t')
num = 0
has = [0]*len(head)
for line in f:
    num += 1
    for (i,x) in enumerate(line.strip().split('\t')):
        if x:
            has[i] += 1

print head
print [float(x)/num for x in has]
```